# Swift 2.3 Nearest Hour (Superior or Equal) from current Date

Tags: ios, swift2, nsdate, hour

I have to determine H and H+3 where H is >= to nearest Hour.

Let me show you some examples :

> if today's hour is 0h00 -> H = 0h and H+3 = 3h
>
> if today's hour is 0h01 -> H = 1h and H+3 = 3h
>
> if today's hour is 21h00 -> H = 21h and H+3 = 0h
>
> if today's hour is 22h34 -> H = 23h and H+3 = 2h (day + 1)

I am new to Swift, I know how to get the nearest hour in Obj C, but with Swift I'm not sure.

Is there a fast way to determine those 2 variables **H** and **H+3** in order to set the text of two labels at any given time.

I tried this method but it gives me the nearest hour but the closest one, not >=.

```
func nextHourDate() -> NSDate? {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let date = NSDate()
    let minuteComponent = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.Minute, fromDate: date)
    let components = NSDateComponents()
    components.minute = 60 - minuteComponent.minute
    return calendar.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: date, options: [])
}
```

I'm developing in Swift 2.3

**EDIT :**

After reading the answers/comments, here is what I developed.

```
func determineH() -> NSDate? {
        let gregorian = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        let now = NSDate()
        let components = gregorian.components([.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: now)

        if components.minute != 0 {
            components.hour = components.hour + 1
            components.minute = 0
        }

        let date = gregorian.dateFromComponents(components)!
        return date
    }
```

Comment: "I'm developing in Swift 2.3" Why? You are "new to Swift" so why learn a language that will be dead any day now? Learn Swift 3, not Swift 2.

Comment: Because I am maintaining an application developed in Swift 2.3. I need to make a release soon. I will be translating the application when I won't be under pressure.

Comment: Good answer. :)

Comment: But thank you for the advice, you are not the only one telling me this. I can't wait to be learning Swift 3, you can't imagine.

Comment: I didn't mean to yank your chain. Apologies.

Comment: Nsdate knows no timezone. Seems ok to me in that regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### based on your code:

check minutes of the current hour and go back to the last full hour and only then add!?

Ill not provide the code for that `arithmetic masterpiece` since you already almost there

### best: work with dateComponents more

only increase the hours property and reset minutes to 0!?

```
comps.hours += 1
comps.minutes = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

To get next hour, you add 1 hour and then drop the minutes.  If you want nextHour(12:00PM) to be 12:00PM instead of 1:00PM then add 59 minutes 59 seconds instead of 1 hour.  Note this doesn't deal with the milliseconds; if you care about that, zero it out also:

```
    extension Date {
        func advancedToNextHour() -> Date? {
            var date = self
            date += TimeInterval(59*60+59)
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let components = calendar.dateComponents([.second, .minute], from: date)
            guard let minutes = components.minute,
                  let seconds = components.second else {
                return nil
            }
            return date - TimeInterval(minutes)*60 - TimeInterval(seconds)
        }
        func advancedToNearest(hours: Int) -> Date? {
            guard let next = advancedToNextHour(), hours > 0 else {
                return nil
            }
            return next + TimeInterval(hours-1)*60*60
        }
    }

    print(Date().advancedToNextHour())
    print(Date().advancedToNearest(hours: 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a Calendar extension like this:

```swift
extension Calendar {
    func nextFullHour(after date: Date) -> Date {
        let components = dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
        
        if components.minute != 0 {
            let fullHour = self.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -components.minute!, to: date)!
            let nextFullHour = self.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: fullHour)!
            return nextFullHour
        }
        
        return date
    }
}
```

And then it would just be `Calendar.current.nextFullHour(after: Date())`